# Find the value of a for valid PDF

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

[image]

I'm confused as how "a" has to do with anything with the PDF as it's not on the RHS?

Comment: You're right - there's probably a typo.

Comment: For $a=n^2$ you have a valid pmf (not pdf).